# problem with loading tcshrc

Tags: tcsh

I have ubuntu 16.04 installed on my local pc and I'm trying to make my work environment as similar to the way it is configured at my job

to achieve that I wanted to use the same tcshrc file (yes, we use tcsh, not sure why...)

anyway, when I try to open a tcsh terminal (or to source ~/.tcshrc for the matter) I'm getting an error:

```
set: Variable name must begin with a letter.
```

trying to isolate the cause I found out that the next lines are enough to cause it

```
#!/bin/tcsh
echo 0
set history = 2000  # this line is not the cause, verified by echoing
echo 1
set savehist = (2000 merge)
echo 2
```

output:

```
0
1
set: Variable name must begin with a letter.
```

when i try to run  **set savehist = (2000 merge)** as a regular shell command the terminal doesn't show any error.

ofcourse that at my job the tcshrc is working fine. in both I have tcsh 6.18.01 installed

any help is welcome

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as answered by ilkkachu [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399610/problem-with-loading-tcshrc), the reason for my .tcshrc not working was that few hidden characters were added to my original .tcshrc that I sent over an email. using `od -c .tcshrc` clearly showed the sneaky characters and once removed everything worked as expected